# How long to wait for Eventual Consistency to propagate in a Selenium test?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create tests to verify that my entities are being saved in the database when using Selenium.
The code works fine when I manually enter the form data but it fails with the automated test.

When I put breakpoints in the post function of the code, I can see that the customer count changes after the record is saved. 
I read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests

I'm using an Ancestor query which I thought would have Strong Consistency so I'm not sure why I'm having these problems at all.

From what I understood, the tests were failing because of Eventual Consistency and the way to get around that was to change the PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy settings.

```
policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)
```

And when I ran the test again I got the same error.

It was also suggested that if I waited for a period of time, Eventual Consistency would have time to propagate.
This didn't work for the test either.

What am I doing wrong with creating these tests?

```
> /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py(130)post()  
-> customer.put()  
(Pdb) l  
125             customer.phone = self.request.get('id_phone')  
126             customer.zipcode = int(self.request.get('id_zip'))  
127             # show original number of customer to show the code works  
128             starting_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
129             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
130  ->         customer.put()  
131             final_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
132             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
133             query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}  
134             self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))  
135       
(Pdb) starting_customer_count  
19  
(Pdb) c  
> /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py(133)post()  
-> query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}  
(Pdb) l     
128             starting_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
129             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
130             customer.put()  
131             final_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
132             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
133  ->         query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}  
134             self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))  
135       
136     config = {}  
137     config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {  
138         'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',  
(Pdb) final_customer_count  
20
```

The entities also show up in the Datastore Viewer.

However, my test keeps failing.

```
$ nosetests --with-gae    
test_guest_can_submit_contact_info (dermalfillersecrets.functional_tests.NewVisitorTest) ... FAIL  

======================================================================  
FAIL: test_guest_can_submit_contact_info (dermalfillersecrets.functional_tests.NewVisitorTest)  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/functional_tests.py", line 75, in test_guest_can_submit_contact_info  
    self.assertNotEqual(orig_customer_count, final_customer_count)  
AssertionError: 0 == 0
```

This is the functional_tests.py file contents:

```
import os, sys  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")  

import unittest  
from selenium import webdriver  
from google.appengine.api import memcache  
from google.appengine.ext import db  
from google.appengine.ext import testbed  
import dev_appserver    
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2  


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):  

    def setUp(self):  
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
        self.testbed.activate()  
        #self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='dermalfillersecrets')  
        self.testbed.init_user_stub()  
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()  
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()  

        # setup the dev_appserver  
        APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']  

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)  

    def tearDown(self):  
        self.browser.quit()  
        self.testbed.deactivate()  


    def test_guest_can_submit_contact_info(self):  
        from main import Client, Customer  
        # below query didn't work because of eventual consistency  
        #query = Customer.query()  
        client = Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()  
        orig_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_name').send_keys("Kallie Wheelock")  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_street').send_keys("123 main st")  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_phone').send_keys('(404)555-1212')  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_zip').send_keys("30306")  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('submit').submit()  
        # this should return 1 more record   
        import time; time.sleep(10)  
        final_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
        self.assertNotEqual(orig_customer_count, final_customer_count)  
        assert(Customer.query(Customer.name == "Kallie Wheelock").get())  
        # Delete the Customer record  
        Customer.query(Customer.name =="Kallie Wheelock").delete()import os, sys  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")  
        sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")  

        import unittest  
        from selenium import webdriver  
        from google.appengine.api import memcache  
        from google.appengine.ext import db  
        from google.appengine.ext import testbed  
        import dev_appserver    
        from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2  


        class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):  

            def setUp(self):  
                self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
                self.testbed.activate()  
                #self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='dermalfillersecrets')  
                self.testbed.init_user_stub()  
                self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()  
                self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()  

                # setup the dev_appserver  
                APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']  

                self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
                self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)  

            def tearDown(self):  
                self.browser.quit()  
                self.testbed.deactivate()  

            def test_guest_can_submit_contact_info(self):  
                from main import Client, Customer  

                client = Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()  
                orig_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
                self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')  
                self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_name').send_keys("Kallie Wheelock")  
                self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_street').send_keys("123 main st")  
                self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_phone').send_keys('(404)555-1212')  
                self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_zip').send_keys("30306")  
                self.browser.find_element_by_name('submit').submit()  
                # this should return 1 more record   
                import time; time.sleep(10)  
                final_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()  
                self.assertNotEqual(orig_customer_count, final_customer_count)  
                assert(Customer.query(Customer.name == "Kallie Wheelock").get())  
                # Delete the Customer record  
                Customer.query(Customer.name =="Kallie Wheelock").delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your testing setup rather than eventual consistency.

There are different instances of the datastore and you need to make sure that you are using the right ones:

1. dev_appserver.py has its own datastore
2. Testbed has it own datastore as well

By default, Testbed does not access the datastore used by dev_appserver.py and vice versa.

Since Selenium uses dev_appserver.py, you need to explicitly tell dev_appserver.py and Testbed to use the same datastore.

Below is a snippet from my testing setup.  I'm not sure that it will run as is but it should get you in the right direction.

Note that I also explicitly start and stop the dev_appserver.py.

```
import subprocess, time, os, unittest, shlex
from google.appengine.ext import db, testbed
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub, apiproxy_stub_map
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Start the dev server
        cmd = "/.../bin/dev_appserver.py /.../app.yaml --storage_path /tmp/datastore --clear_datastore --skip_sdk_update_check"
        self.dev_appserver = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), 
                                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(2) # Important, let dev_appserver start up
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.setup_env(app_id="dev~myapp")
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_app_identity_stub()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(
            datastore_file="/tmp/datastore/datastore.db", use_sqlite=True)
        self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
        self.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
        self.testbed.init_user_stub()
        self.testbed.init_mail_stub()
        self.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()        
        self.taskqueue_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('taskqueue')
        self.mail_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('mail')
        self.datastore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3')
        # Start the headless browser for Selenium tests
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()
        self.driver.quit()
        self.dev_appserver.terminate()
```

Comment: I think you are right that the problem was using 2 separate datastores. 
Unfortunately, I can't use pdb to debug errors using when dev_appserver starts up in the test.

Comment: After posting this, I was motivated to try running it again, and it isn't working for me anymore...  I'm getting weird errors by accessing the same datastore from both testbed and dev_appserver.py.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to test?

If you try to test the code that saves the entity, then you can write a simple unit test: save entity, check that it was saved.

If you try to test the client code, then introducing the delay breaks the idea of such testing. Upper limit on eventual consistency is not guaranteed. Your UI code should be able to handle any time delay - from none to a few seconds at least.

For example, if the number of entities is important for continuation of a user work flow, most apps would block the UI (e.g. show some kind of a progress bar or spinner) until the call is successfully completed. If waiting for this entity being saved is not part of the user workflow, then there is no need to test it in Selenium - again, you can write a simple unit test.